# Rotating 3d .obj file using jsc3d.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using the jsc3d.js javascript library to draw an .obj file on the canvas (see: http://heliconbooks.com/article/heartdemo&lang=en)

I want to draw 4 buttons around it to rotate is using mouse clicks.
I tried

```
<input type="button" value="Rotate left" onClick="viewer.rotMatrix.rotateAboutXAxis(-10)" />
```

But it did not rotate.

Does anyone have any idea how to rotate it?
My JavaScript knowledge is not too good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the view after rotation using viewer.update();

you can use following code for your rotation  buttons.

```
    <input type="button" value="Rotate down" onClick="viewer.rotate(-10,0,0);viewer.update();"/> 
<input type="button" value="Rotate up" onClick="viewer.rotate(10,0,0);viewer.update();"/> 
<input type="button" value="Rotate left" onClick="viewer.rotate(0,-10,0);viewer.update();"/> 
<input type="button" value="Rotate right" onClick="viewer.rotate(0,10,0);viewer.update();"/>
```